# Удаление циклов из графа в SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, графы

Предположим, у вас есть таблица рёбер со столбцами A и B, в которых указаны номера вершин, соединенных ребром. Как выбрать из неё ребра так, чтобы в выборке не оказалось ни одного ребра, создающего цикл? Пример:

```
| A | B |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 4 | 1 |
```

Результат запроса:

```
| A | B |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 1 |
```

Или

```
| A | B |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 1 |
```

Или любая другая комбинация, которая не создает циклов, т.к. добавив хоть одну строку из начальной таблицы появится цикл.

Небольшая визуализация
[image: визуализация]

Comment: Ну например: 1. Берём случайное ребро и считаем его текущим графом 2. Берём случайное ребро, присоединённое к текущему графу, но не образующему цикла, добавляем его в текущий граф. 3. Повторяем пункт 2, пока получается. 4. Выводим полученный граф.

Comment: Альтернативно: 1. Проверяем, что граф связный. Если нет, делим его на связные и берём любой из них. 2. Находим в графе цикл. Удаляем из него любое ребро так, чтобы граф оставался связным. 3. Повторяем пункт 2, пока получается. 4. Выводим полученный граф.

Comment: @Akina если удалить из цикла одно ребро - граф в любом случае останется связным.

Comment: @Akina вопрос именно в реализации. Второй алгоритм я с ходу даже не представляю как реализовать, а первый, полагаю, можно реализовать через хранение пути в еще одном строковом столбце и проверку проходили ли мы через вершину через поиск по строке.

Comment: Oracle+поиск в глубину. Остов дерева ещё можно загуглить. Я могу в виде ответа это написать, но в интернете гораздо больше других решений, можно выбирать.